# Android localization for RTL languages

Tags: android, localization, arabic, hebrew, right-to-left

I need to add localization features to my app for RTL languages (hebrew and arabic)
How can I modify the layout in order for the picture to be aligned differently in the RTL option?

For example: in the main menu I got buttons on the left side and pic on the right (in the LTR version) I need to reverse it and not only change the pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the localization label for RTL languages then save their custom layout xml files under the folder "res/layout-RtlLabel/customLayout.xml". For example "layout-fr"... [look here for more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: Also i did not check if any label exists for RTL languages... If not, you can handle it with code with fetching locale from configuration... Still RTL languages you called has to be labelled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
android:layoutDirection="locale"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```